# How can I unset existing storage integration or credentials in Snowflake stage

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I original built one Snowflake stage by using credentials.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE "TO_S3"."EXTERNAL_STAGES".AWS_STAGE
    URL = 'S3://xxx'
    CREDENTIALS = (AWS_ROLE = 'arn:aws:iam::xxx');
```

But now I like to use storage integration to replace the credentials.
So I create one storage integration and SET this integration in my stage:

```
create or replace storage integration s3_int
    type = external_stage
    storage_provider = s3
    enabled = TRUE
    storage_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::xxx'
    storage_allowed_locations = ('S3://xxx');

ALTER STAGE "TO_S3"."EXTERNAL_STAGES".AWS_STAGE SET STORAGE_INTEGRATION = s3_int;
```

But after SET integration into existing stage, how can I deal with the CREDENTIALS I initially gave? Do I need to DROP/UNSET it?

I actually tried to use UNSET to remove the credentials:

```
ALTER STAGE "TO_S3"."EXTERNAL_STAGES".AWS_STAGE UNSET CREDENTIALS
```

But it shows me the following error:

```
Unsupported feature 'UNSET'.
```

Why cannot I use UNSET in this case? Why it says the UNSET is not supported?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could just run "CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE" again by removing the "CREDENTIALS" part and include the "INTEGRATION" part.